# Error Running Android Project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-virtual-device

When I run my android project in Intellij IDEA using an AVD I get this error

android-apt-compiler: Cannot run program "/Users/myAccount/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem, occurs in IntelliJ Ultimate, 12.1.3 on Mac. There is a bug report http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107311, vote please!

Comment: Check: [ADT 22 - missing aapt.exe after upgrading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585099/adt-22-missing-aapt-exe-after-upgrading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was successfully resolving on mac 10.8

copied only aapt and lib\dx.jar and dx

from build-tools/18.0.1
to
platform-tools

Answer (score 6):

Yeah according to Simon in 
[Android Hello-World compile error: Intellij cannot find aapt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588969/android-hello-world-compile-error-intellij-cannot-find-aapt)
"It appears that the latest update to the r22 SDK release moved aapt and the lib jar from the platform-tools to the build-tools directory. While we wait for JetBrains to release an update, here's a quick fix using a couple of symbolic links for Unix users:

From your AndroidSDK/platform-tools directory, run the following:

```
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aapt aapt
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/lib lib
```

...and IntelliJ should be able to compile as normal.
"

Unfortunately copying is the easier way around this on windows... 
unless you use something like

```
mklink /H C:\Users\Tom\androidsdk\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe C:\Users\Tom\androidsdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe
```

in the command prompt to attempt to make a hard link window's style of the file to your platform tools folder.

caveat I haven't tried this though...

Comment: Worth noting that you'll need to change the version number to match the version you have installed - in my case it was 18.0.1, not 17.0.0...

Answer (score 4):

I solve this problem on WIn by copy all files from android-sdk/build-tools/17.0.0 to platform-tools folder.

Answer (score 0):

i copied only `aapt.exe` and `lib\dx.jar`

from *build-tools\android-4.2.2*

to

*platform-tools*