# aapt missing MACOS Use the `android' tool to install the "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Tags: aapt

aapt missing MACOS Use the `android' tool to install the "Android SDK Platform-tools".

i have already use android download times.
but i can't find any usefully aapt file 
only link to /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r22.0.1/platform-tools/aapt 
but under /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r22.0.1/platform-tools/  only adb

Answer (score 2):

the "aapt" tool was moved to the Build Tools folder. Run "android" and make sure you install the build tools (18.1 is currently the latest one).

also see this other post:
[Android Maven Could not find tool 'aapt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619143/android-maven-could-not-find-tool-aapt)

Answer (score 0):

Run the *android* command and ensure that the SDK tools for your target platform are up to date. It is possible that you updated the SDK but not the build tools.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The android tools from brew expect version 17 of the SDK Build-tools to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently and found it to be an error with my HomeBrew setup. I think HomeBrew was expecting a particular version of the build tools that I didn't have.

I found that updating HomeBrew

`brew update`

gave me a new error which was much more informative:

```
It appears you do not have 'build-tools-19.0.3' installed.
Use the 'android' tool to install them: 
    android update sdk --no-ui --filter 'build-tools-19.0.3'
```

Unfortunately the filter in the suggested command didn't work but I found I could install it manually through the UI by running the `android` tool and selecting the version HomeBrew was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585846/440362 for correct answer. The file's directory has changed from tools to build-tools/