# Download Android SDK Tools Revision 21.1 JDeveloper / ADF Mobile

Tags: java, android, maven, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I want to download the Android SDK Tools Revision 21.1. I have seen [android website](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) but I have found no way to download it. It is required as I am working on JDeveloper [ADF Mobile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/setupmobileapps/jdtut_11r2_54_2.html) and it follows the Android SDKs old directory structure.

Although It is good practice to work with latest SDKs, but here I have problem working with **Revision 22** as JDeveloper doesn't support latest Android SDK directory structure (**Rev 22**).

For **JDeveloper**: Following links might give them why I need old SDK version.

- [JDeveloper / ADF Mobile and Android SDK (Rev 22) incompatibilty](http://pitss.com/us/2013/05/17/jdeveloperadf-mobile-and-android-sdk-rev-22-incompatibility/)
- [ADF Mobile - Deploying to Android fails with "Cannot find program ... aapt"](https://blogs.oracle.com/onesizedoesntfitall/entry/adf_mobile_deploying_to_android)
- [ADT 22 - missing aapt.exe after upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585099/adt-22-missing-aapt-exe-after-upgrading). This link provides solution but it uses [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) and I don't want to use it at this time. Moreover! I couldn't understand it.

Let me know how to download **Rev 21.x** or provide me the solution of this problem. One solution the above link gave was to copy and paste the required files from `build-tools` to `platform-tools` but still, it didn't solve the issue.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it is working with `C:\AndroidSDK\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2`.

This part I took it from the Mobile Developer's Guide for Oracle Application Development Framework (Deploying ADF Mobile applications)

Note:

The structure of the SDK tools is changed in the release of Revision 22, 
with the build tools components relocated from the platform-tools directory to the build-tools directory.

To enable deployment, the Android Build Tools Location field must reference the location of one of these build tools, the aapt file (`aapt.exe` on Windows systems).

The location of this file differs depending on the SDK revision.

For Revision 22, this file is located within the build-tools directory (such as SDK `Installation\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\build-tools\ Android-4.n`).

For earlier revisions, it is located within the platform-tools directory (such as SDK `Installation\adt-bundle-windows-x86\platfrom-tools`). 
ADF Mobile queries the Android SDK for the location of the appt file and populates the Android Build Tools Location field accordingly.

For Revision 22 of the SDK, ADF Mobile populates the field with the latest version of the build-tools directory that is installed on the development computer.

For revisions prior to 22, ADF Mobile populates the field with the location of the platform-tools directory. In this case, the field is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

After spending plenty of time I have found its solution. Although the solution is not a proper solution as **Oracle** needs to fix it.

Copy all the files (**aapt.exe** and **dx.bat**) from **build-tools** folder to **platform-tools** folder in Android SDK.

Now, copy **java.exe** file from **System32** folder to **SysWOW64** and you are done. [It works for me](https://community.oracle.com/message/12369178). This is a temporary solution and you can get your work going.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@faizan this issue is for android API 19 and above.Oracle has not come up with a permenant solution.Instead of using the temporary solution you mentioned above...use API 17 i.e 4.2.2
Install sdk platform for API 17 and build tools for API 17 and then you will not face this error.It works smoothly.
Working on API 17 is bugfree and stable as of now.Also attaching a screenshot for your reference.
    [image]